# Unity Facebook AppRequest Crash

Tags: facebook, crash, unity-game-engine, facebook-app-requests, facebook-unity-sdk

We are using the Facebook Unity plugin build to device, open the AppRequest dialog, scroll up and down once or twice and the app crashes.

**SDK Info**
SDK Version: 4.3.4
Build Version: 131022.2bb3e6026790434

**Code**

```
FB.AppRequest("Come join me in Tunnel Town!", null, "", null,
              100, "", "Invite Friends", InviteUsersCallback);
```

**Crash Report**
Download [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60541766/TunnelTown%20%2011-15-13%204-05%20PM.crash)

**Video Example**
Download [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60541766/IMG_0175.MOV).

**Device Information**

- iPad 4 running iOS 7.0.3
- iPod 4 running iOS 5.1.1
- iPad 3 running iOS 6.1.3
- Many others (aka we have a lot of devices and it crashes on all of them)

**Misc. Info**

- It doesn't crash when using a Facebook account with no buddies
- Our app has plenty of free memory (at least when running on the iPad 4) and the crash report is not a "low-memory" report, as far as I can tell.
- This bug was also present in SDK version 4.3.3, build version 131013.cbd3dd67f02d59d

Anyone seen this? Any other info you would like? Thanks in advance!

[EDIT] We were able to solve this by following this workaround: forum.unity3d.com/threads/203506-Workaround-ios7-DisplayLink-Scrolling-results-in-crash

Comment: So far we haven't been able to repro this.  Any chance you can send us a project that produces the crash?

Comment: I will try to get an empty project breaking and send you it as soon as I can.

Comment: What version of Unity are you using?

Comment: Sorry guys - we were busy getting the build out and updated. We were using Unity 4.2.1. We have upgraded to 4.3 now that we have submitted to Apple so I will be working on getting a basic project setup. We did realize that we have another webview (not using the Facebook) plugin and it also has the scrolling crash so I don't think it's a Facebook plugin problem.

Answer (score 0):

in Unity 4.3 that bug was fixed. Try to update Unity.

"iOS: Fixed various scrolling related crashes on iOS 7".

Comment: We upgraded to Unity 4.3.0f4 and the latest FB plugin (SDK 4.3.4) and it still breaks. We found this last night and it seems to be working :) I can still get it to crash if I scroll like a mad man but it doesn't crash nearly as often as before: http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/203506-Workaround-ios7-DisplayLink-Scrolling-results-in-crash

Comment: have any idea for fix it?

Comment: Yes, we were able to fix this by using this workaround: http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/203506-Workaround-ios7-DisplayLink-Scrolling-results-in-crash